# Algorithm for determining member-bound subintervals of an interval

Tags: algorithm

Given a list of items with start and end times (e.g. start days and end days [up to but not including] in a calendar month), what are the minimum number of spanning intervals that can be constructed bounded by members in any one interval and what members are present in the aforementioned intervals? I think an example will make this more clear (feels like I don't have the right vocabulary to describe the problem):

**Input**: [A,B,C,D,E]

```
A: 1,3
B: 2,4
C: 1,10
D: 5,7
E: 5,10
```

**Output**:

```
1-2: A,C
2-3: A,B,C
3-4: B,C
4-5: C
5-7: C,D,E
7-10: C,E
```

If there was a gap I'd also want to know that (say 4-5 wasn't covered by any item).

I've considered basic walks of each item and min-max considerations, BSTs, and Interval trees in particular but I kind of feel lost as to what the best approach is here. Thanks!

Comment: You're right, fixed (should be 2-4: A,B,C I think though).

Comment: You're right again. Sorry about that. I've sort of fried my brain today thinking about this.

Answer (score 0):

- Step 1: iterate over the items, building a list of entries of the form { day 1, start of A } and { day 3, end of A }.
- Step 2: sort this list by day.
- Step 3: combine entries from the same day, giving entries like { day 5, [ start D, start E ] }.

(Note: since the days are all in a single month, you know beforehand what all the possible days are — and there aren't many — so you can combine all three of the above steps into one straightforward pass by using bucket sort with up to 31 buckets.)

- Step 4: iterate over the combined entries, keeping track of items that have started but not yet ended, and generating the desired output.